# Large number of SQL Active Sessions when injecting DBContext using Autofac in WebApi

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, dbcontext

I'm using `Autofac` for injecting dependencies in `Web Api`.

I set `InstancePerRequest` scope for EF `DBContext`.

`Autofac` Wiring up configuration:

```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();

        var asmb = typeof (TrafficDataService).Assembly;
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asmb).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();


        builder.RegisterType<TrafficServiceGlobalContext>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<EMSEntities>().As<IEmsDataModel>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ViolationTrafficEntities>().As<IViolationDataModel>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<TrafficController>().As<IHttpController>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();


        var container = builder.Build();

        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
```

After Service gets huge number of request, and when checking Active Sessions for my DB i see 500 Active Sessions over db.

Is really this a problem?
How to implement Connection Pooling?
Any idea?

**Update:**
All relevant classes depends on interfaces.
As Yacoub Massad asked in comments area, here is some of relevant classes signature and constructors:

```
    public partial class ViolationTrafficEntities : DbContext, IViolationDataModel
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }        
public class TrafficDataService : ITrafficDataService
    {
        private readonly IViolationDataModel _violationDataModel;
        public TrafficDataService(IViolationDataModel violationDataModel)
        {
            _violationDataModel = violationDataModel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: .Net has its own connection pooling. But that's a different question anyway. As for the hanging sessions. Does *one single* request keep an open session too?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for responding.
Many multiple connections created and after a long time closed automatically, but count of connections is large, somtimes about 700 connections.

Comment: I see you have interfaces for your `DbContext` class. Does all the relevant classes depend on the interfaces (e.g. `IEmsDataModel`)? or does some of them depend on the concrete classes directly (e.g. `EMSEntities`)? Can you show some examples of the constructors of the relevant classes?

Comment: @YacoubMassad All of relevant classes depends on the interfaces. I have updated post and add signature and constructor of some relevant classes.
Check it out.

Comment: How many requests where there? Maybe there were enough requests to justify these connections. Can you confirm that multiple instances of your context classes where created in a single request? How many subclasses of `DbContext` are there? Please note that in a single request, if you depend on multiple context classes, an instance of each one will be created since they are different classes, each one will open a connection.

Comment: @YacoubMassad About 150-250 requests per second served. For a single request just create a single instance of `DbContext`. Have any idea?

Comment: Yes, but can you confirm that your code creates more than one instance per requests? And assuming if it did, do you want all `DbContext` derived classes instances to use a single connection? There is a constructor of `DbContext` that accepts a `DbConnection`. You might be able to use that.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Each request create just create one instance and I use `IntancePerRequest()` life cycle scope for kill connection after ending request life. But in action connection kept alive and stay in active seasions in SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99781/discussion-between-mojtaba-and-yacoub-massad).